# Не работает вызов метода в плагине jQuery

Tags: jquery, плагин

Есть плагин для jQuery. Вешаю его на input. При событии onkeydown должен срабатывать метод KeyDown. Но в ответ в консоли вижу такое:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'KeyDown'
```

В написании плагинов новичок, сильно не пинайте.

```
; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    function Plugin(element, options) {

        var defaults = {
            width: 270,
            height: 300
        };

        this.element = element;
        this.el = $(element);
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function () {
            this.el.on('keydown', function (e) { this.KeyDown(e); });
        },

        KeyDown: function (e) {
            console.log('Yeah!!!');
        }

    };

    $.fn.myplugin = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_myplugin')) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_myplugin',
                new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема состоит в данном случае в scope:

```
this.el.on('keydown', function (e) { 
      this.KeyDown(e);
});
```

this - который находится внутри функции, он не относится к объекту Plugin. Он относится к элементу с которым Вы работаете. Чтобы исправить это, нужно определить переменную instance объекта:

```
init: function() {  
    var _this = this;

    this.el.on('keydown', function (e) {
        _this.KeyDown(e);
    }); 
},
```

Comment: @zhenyab: опередили немного :)

Answer (score 2):

В анонимной функции обработки `keydown` у Вас `this` уже не имеет отношения к Вашему плагину. Соответственно не имеет метода KeyDown.

Измените:

```
this.el.on('keydown', function (e) { this.KeyDown(e); });
```

на:

```
this.el.on('keydown', this.KeyDown);
```